# Django OAuth and SAML

Tags: django, authentication, oauth, saml

I have a Django application and I have no experience on logins topics, so I would like to know if it is possible to integrate both authentication systems.
SAML for some users (University f.e.) and OAuth (google, facebook,etc) for other users.

Is it that possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: yaa possible, you have to write your custom authentication backend?

Comment: And  what about to use allauth for local users and saml for university users?